# "TypeError: can't pickle sqlite3.Cursor objects" when trying to query sqlite db with Flask on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, pickle

I'm trying to bring a small flask app online using PythonAnywhere. I used SqlAlchemy with MySql first but would get the typeError in the title whenever I tried to query stuff through my app. I then moved to using Sqlite3 thinking that it might solve the problem, but it still persists.

Before trying to port it to PythonAnywhere, I used Sqlite and hosted it on my own machine. I used SqlAlchemy and MySql first because it was recommended. There isn't a problem with my queries, as they always work when I execute them through the console.

Here is my code:

```
def register():

    if request.method == "POST":
        [unnecessary code snipped out]
        # This is a dummy query, I cut the original out because it was too  
        # long and unnecessary, but both produce the same error
        result = db.execute("""select * from users""")
        if not result:
            return apology("Username already exists.")

        # remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = result

        # redirect user to home page
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
```

The function should redirect the user to index if they successfully register and the query should work, but instead I get this error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/8BitRebellion/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/8BitRebellion/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1835, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/8BitRebellion/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1852, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/8BitRebellion/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2133, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/8BitRebellion/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 355, in save_session
    total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime))
  File "/home/8BitRebellion/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/cache.py", line 839, in set
    pickle.dump(value, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
TypeError: can't pickle sqlite3.Cursor objects
```

I don't understand why this error is triggered, and there are similar errors when I search it up but none of them are related to this.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: SOLVED
Thanks to @roganjosh, I realized that the problem was with the way I performed the query, not the way the query was processed, as I initially thought.

Comment: `session["user_id"] = result.fetchall()`. You haven't fetched any results so you still have a cursor object

Comment: But that part of the code doesn't execute before the error pops up. That line worked fine before I tried to port too

Comment: The traceback does not show what line of your code causes the initial error

Comment: But the error is related to my query as far as I can see. EDIT: I tried your code and still get the same error

Comment: It isn't related to your query. `result = db.execute("""select * from users""")` returns a cursor _object_, not a list of results. `session["user_id"] = result` shouldn't work, because the data needs to be serialized when it is stored in a session dict. However, that serialization is based on JSON as far as I know, so the origin of the `pickle` error is unclear, but it's still the issue that you're trying to serialize a cursor object and not the query results

Comment: Yeah I used to use a module that built on top of that that didn't require me to use `fetchall`. However, that still doesn't help with the pickle issue

Comment: I can see the discrepancy between my suggestion and the issue you're facing, but something almost certainly is missing from the question. The general issue is the same, but there's not enough info to piece it together. Perhaps something in `[unnecessary code snipped out]` is being overlooked here, or that that traceback you've given is the "result of another exception". _Your_ code does not feature anywhere in that traceback, but presumably it's something you have done that causes the error.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that my code was indeed incorrect. I just rechecked the error log and the errors are on a different view, for the index function, but thats because I haven't implemented that part yet. Thanks for your reply. Could you please put that in an answer so I can mark it solved. Thanks.

Comment: I will post an answer, but please [edit] the question to make it consistent because I don't actually have anything to base the answer on other than a general sense of the problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196835/discussion-between-toyotasupra-and-roganjosh).